# In Outlook 2016, how can you preview pictures separately attached to emails?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I wish to have pictures separately attached to (and NOT within the body of) incoming emails automatically previewed, to avert the inefficiency in manually right-clicking each picture and then selecting `Preview`.

Answer (score 0):

> ### [Change whether pictures in messages are automatically downloaded](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-whether-pictures-in-messages-are-automatically-downloaded-020abc02-4876-47fa-9cb1-2b4543154311)
>
> > > *Applies To: Outlook 2016 , Outlook 2013*
> >
> > <sub>*By default, **Outlook 2013 later** blocks pictures which are downloaded from the internet.*</sub>
> >
> > - <sub>Helps you avoid viewing potentially offensive material (when external    content is linked to the message).</sub>
> > - <sub>Helps to keep malicious code from damaging the data on your computer.</sub>
> > - <sub>If you are on a low-bandwidth connection, blocking allows you to    decide whether a particular image warrants the time and bandwidth that are required for downloading it.</sub>
> >
> > <sub>*Pictures in email messages that are actually linked and downloaded from the Internet can also be used as a way to confirm that you opened
> >     the message. This is known as a web beacon. For example, a junk email
> >     sender can confirm that they have reached an active email address when
> >     the picture in the message is downloaded.*</sub>
>
> **Unblock picture downloads for all messages**
>
> 1. Click the **File** tab.
> 2. Click **Options**.
> 3. Click **Trust Center**.
> 4. Under **Microsoft Outlook Trust Center**, click **Trust Center Settings**.
> 5. Clear the **Don't download pictures automatically in HTML e-mail
>      messages or RSS items** check box.
>
> **Unblock picture downloads for all messages from an email address or domain**
>
> 1. In an open message that was sent from that email address or domain,
>      right-click one of the blocked items.
> 2. Click **Add Sender to Safe Senders List** or **Add the Domain @domain to
>      Safe Senders List**.
>
> <sub>[source](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-whether-pictures-in-messages-are-automatically-downloaded-020abc02-4876-47fa-9cb1-2b4543154311)</sub>

Comment: Sorry, but your answer does not appear to answer my question? My question concerns pictures attached, not within the email's body itself.

Comment: @Timere - I assume you have tried this solution?  You should edit your question, because its not clear, your talking about the attachtments instead of the inline images (which are still considered attachtments in Outlook)

Comment: @Timere Now that you've changed the criteria in your question, I'm not certain if this is even possible (at least with native options) but there may be some behind the scenes VBA you could write or something to perform the operation when applicable. To me though, auto opening an attachment in a preview is just a dangerous as having them auto open regularly within Outlook for security reasons.... Read over this which I assume you already know and DOES NOT answer your question to auto open these in preview without selecting the option.

Comment: @Timere I forget the link URL so here it is for what I was saying to read over... too long for other comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Preview-attachments-409b6597-346e-416f-abd7-b1e89259fc84